# Tiled rendering of viewports bigger than GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, 3d, openinventor

I'm creating a class that takes an OpenGL scenegraph and uses `QGLFrameBufferObject` to render the result. To support (virtually) infinite sizes I'm using tiling to extract many small images that can be combined into a big image after rendering all tiles.

I do tiling by setting up a viewport (`glViewport`) for the entire image and then using `glScissor` to "cut out" tile after tile. This works fine for resolutions up to `GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS`, but will result in empty tiles outside this limit.

How should I approach this problem? Do I need to alter the camera or is there any neat tricks to do this? I'm using Coin/OpenInventor so any tips specific to these frameworks are very welcome too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the camera isn't as hard as you may think, and it's the only solution I can see at all apart from modifying vertex shaders.

By scaling and translating the projection matrix along the x and y axes, you can easily get any subregion of the normal camera's view.

For a given max and min of the viewport, where the full viewport is (-1, -1) and (1, 1), translate by (max + min) / 2, and scale by (max - min) / 2.

Comment: I ended up adjusting the view volume using [SbViewVolume::narrow](http://doc.coin3d.org/Coin/classSbViewVolume.html#a10f0ca68486f3dc6fa9253e705573d5a) to narrow the rendered "window".

Answer (score 1):

Give the [OpenGL Tile Rendering Library](https://web.archive.org/web/20161222165831/http://www.mesa3d.org/brianp/TR.html) a try.

Answer (score 0):

You could try scaling the entire world down, indirectly making the viewport max account for larger detail. Or basically, you could scale the image AND the viewport down and have the same visual effect.

Comment: That would not let me produce images larger than `GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS`, which is essential.

Comment: It depends on how much larger you want them to be. This would work up to a certain point specifically for VISUAL effects.